# How to match elements with some class from a CSS stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/qa6osv6z/)**.

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css';
hotel-btn-container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
hotel-btn {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: table; width: 100%;">
  <p style="display: table-cell; text-align: center;">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="tel:2125550101">Call Us</a>
  </p>
  <p style="display: table-cell; text-align: center;">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"  target="_blank">Website</a>
  </p>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="hotel-btn-container">
  <p class="hotel-btn">
    <a class="btn btn-primary hotel-btn" href="#">Call Us</a>
  </p>
  <p class="hotel-btn">
    <a class="btn btn-primary hotel-btn" href="#">Website</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

I have two buttons side-by-side with inline CSS. The buttons display properly.

```html
<div style="display: table; width: 100%;">
    <p style="display: table-cell; text-align: center;">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="tel:2125550101">Call Us</a>
    </p>
    <p style="display: table-cell; text-align: center;">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"  target="_blank">Website</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

However, when I place the same styles in the stylesheet...

```css
hotel-btn-container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
hotel-btn {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And call the classes in HTML, it's not displaying the buttons side-be-side.

```html
<div class="hotel-btn-container">
    <p class="hotel-btn">
        <a class="btn btn-primary hotel-btn" href="#">Call Us</a>
    </p>
    <p class="hotel-btn">
        <a class="btn btn-primary hotel-btn" href="#">Website</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

---

I have pre-pended the classes with the word "hotel" (relevant to my project), so I know there's nothing overriding it.

Answer (score 10):

The class selectors begin with `.`:

> [**5.8.3 Class selectors**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#class-html)
>
> Working with HTML, authors may use the period (`.`) notation as an
>   alternative to the `~=` notation when representing the `class`
>   attribute. Thus, for HTML, `div.value` and `div[class~=value]` have
>   the same meaning. The attribute value must immediately follow the
>   "period" (`.`).

So your code should be

```
.hotel-btn-container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.hotel-btn {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css';
.hotel-btn-container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.hotel-btn {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="hotel-btn-container">
  <p class="hotel-btn">
    <a class="btn btn-primary hotel-btn" href="#">Call Us</a>
  </p>
  <p class="hotel-btn">
    <a class="btn btn-primary hotel-btn" href="#">Website</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

In your external CSS, you are missing the `.` selector. So, you you need to replace the classes in the external CSS as follows

```
.hotel-btn-container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.hotel-btn {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Read more about the selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

Answer (score 2):

**Dude..**

```
class="dude"
```

means call with a `.`

```
.dude { }
```

and

```
id="dude1"
```

means call with a `#`

```
#dude1 { }
```

The only times you can omit is if your calling global HTML tags,

*ie:*

```
<div>


div { }
```

Though bad practice, terrible for maintenance and scale-ability.

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as to say bad practice, they are very handy for CSS resets in media queries ^^

Comment: Agree to disagree my friend.